# How to join a Microsoft Teams meeting with video just from the Meeting ID and passcode?

Tags: linux, chrome, video, browser, microsoft-teams

There seem to be different kinds of Microsoft Teams links.  For example, when I generate a link using the Teams For Linux app, they're of the form:

```
https://teams.live.com/meet/55366767345647
```

But some invitations are more like:

> Microsoft Teams meeting
>
> Join on your computer, mobile app or room device
>
> Click here to join the meeting
>
> Meeting ID: 123 456 411 131 Passcode: CdWX5S
>
> Download Teams | Join on the web
>
> Or call in (audio only)
>
> +1 437-123-7890,,562462542#   Canada, Toronto
>
> Phone Conference ID: 123 678 891#
>
> Find a local number | Reset PIN

Where the link is like:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_MmE2dghgjthggfgftdgk4NTEx%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2284fa96df-e750-41d3-81b1-850387a4aa42%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%2221d05281-6ac1-49f3-b759-5gfdsgfgfgfsfh82c%22%7d
```

and so the question is how to join through the above link with video.  Because I just get caught in a loop of logging in and starting the app without ever joining the meeting itself.

Can I enter this meeting ID into the Teams For Linux app somehow?  I see no such option.

System info:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ chromium --version
Chromium 112.0.5615.49 snap
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Can I not simply enter the meeting ID somewhere?

[image: teams]

There's no such option readily apparent.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux App has been deprecated for all practical purposes. (And I wouldn't know where to enter a meeting code or a URL even if it wasn't.)

What works for me is using the linux version of Microsoft Edge to open these links.

Comment: aha, hugely helpful.  If you'll add a screenshot that would be a bonus for me.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders I'd love to, but of what specifically?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of joining a meeting by ID and where to click?  Oh, I see, you don't know where to enter the link, either!  It's soooo weird.  I just installed Edge.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1467296/847449